# How to change label of simple form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I Have a code in my project like

```
<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :twitter %>
</div>
```

It gives label as `Twitter` in my website. How it produce label with out giving label parameter. I want to change label to something else like `Tweet it`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add label in very simple way

```
<%= f.input :twitter, label: 'Tweet it' %>
```

Check this  [simple_form usage](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage)

If you want to disable label

```
<%= f.input :input_field_name, label: false %>
```

Add custom class to label

```
<%= f.input :field_name, label_html: { class: 'my_class' } %>
```